# LineageID error for a LineageID that doesn't exist

Tags: ssis

I am working on an `SSIS` package that has two data flow elements. In the first one, I have an SQL query of `OLE DB` source, which I eventually aggregate and feed into a cache transform. The second one has the same SQL query, and performs a lookup on the cache. But whenever I try and run/debug the package, I get this error message:

### TITLE: Package Validation Error

> Package Validation Error
>
> ------------------------------ ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> Error at Set Up Aggregate Info Cache [SSIS.Pipeline]: input column
>   "MasterPolicyNumber" (50) has lineage ID 161 that was not previously
>   used in the Data Flow task.
>
> Error at Set Up Aggregate Info Cache [SSIS.Pipeline]: "component
>   "Aggregate 1" (43)" failed validation and returned validation status
>   "VS_NEEDSNEWMETADATA".
>
> Error at Set Up Aggregate Info Cache [SSIS.Pipeline]: One or more
>   component failed validation.
>
> Error at Set Up Aggregate Info Cache: There were errors during task
>   validation.
>
> (Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.VsIntegration)

When I'm looking at the control flow of the package, the first data flow ("Set Up Aggregate Info Cache") has the red X for an error, but no individual components in the data flow do, and I've scoured all the advanced editors I could find, but the column in question, `MasterPolicyNumber`, doesn't seem to have a LineageID of 161 anywhere.  Any insight on how to correct whatever I'm doing wrong would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

"VS_NEEDSNEWMETADATA" means that the schema has changed from the first time you designed the component. Open that component again and remap/reconfigure the available columns.

The whole thing is tricky and nobody will be able to help you here, since you need to actually manipulate the components and open them in design mode for the metadata to refresh.

This is particularly painful sometimes in data sources and data destinations, destination being the worse offender and sometimes you just have to delete the destination and re-create it.

Comment: I'm still a beginner with SSIS - came from a job where I used SAS so honestly, I have no idea how to do that, or what do to it on (or really honestly, what most of you just said even means).  By component do you mean a specific transformation that is giving me an error? Or the OLE DB source itself?

Comment: @GraceFix I understand your confusion, let me try to explain better. Inside a Data Flow Task you have a datasource object and a destination one. if you change the columns in the source itself (like editing the source file, or the query that gets data from a database), then the mappings of your transformation are no longer valid. Open the transformation remap the columns and save n' pray ;)

Comment: in most cases just by looking at your mappings and saving (ok'ing your changes) is enough.